# Use relative path inside .ini files

Tags: php, path, ini

I created a .user.ini in the root of my website https://www.example.com with only one line:

```
auto_prepend_file = "/path/to/my/website/includes/prepend.php"
```

It is working fine.

I am now setting up a development environment at https://***development***.example.com I copied all the files from my production site to the development site.

Is there a way to rewrite my .user.ini to use relative path? Something like this:

```
auto_prepend_file = doc_root + "/includes/prepend.php"
```

or maybe

```
auto_prepend_file = "includes/prepend.php"
```

This way I don't have to remember to update the .user.ini file each time I am working with production or development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the relative path inside the ini-file and add the doc-root later during the "auto-prepend" process in your php logic.

You can obtain your document root in your index.php via

```php
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', __DIR__);
```

and use it everywhere in your scripts you like to.

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-prepend process"? The .user.ini is processed before index.php So it should be able to point to the correct prepend.php file. By the time index.php is processed, it is too late to define the path to prepend.php Unless I am missing something? Thanks.

Comment: you are most likely missing to tell us what application you are using. if you have a php script which has its entry point in the index.php file there wont be any ini files processed before it.

Comment: It is a php script. In php we can define a prepend file that is attached to the top of all php scripts, including index.php. You typically define the prepend file in an ini file. I am fine when I use absolute path in the ini file. My question is if it is possible to use relative path. Thanks again for your help.